# Approximation of an $L^1-$ function of two variables by trigonometric polynomials.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-series, approximation

We know as a theorem that the trigonometric polynomials are dense in $L^1([0,1))$

For instance for a Lebesgue integrable function we use the Fejer kernel $$F(x)=\sum_{n=-N}^N(1-\frac{|n|}{N+1})e^{2\pi inx}$$ and we take $f*F(x)$
where $''*''$ denotes the convolution of two functions.

Is there an analogue of this theorem in two dimensions,i.e in $L^1([0,1)^2)$?

If there is,then where can i find o proof of this result?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Stone Weierstrass

Comment: I think this would work: $$\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x',y')F_N(x-x')F_M(y-y')dxdy$$.